# How to get the Liana Jungle award?

Tags: paradise-island

How to get the Liana Jungle award? As I suppose, I need to plant enough trees (Liana Trees)?

But how many trees should it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the Liana Jungle award, you need to plant 30 Liana trees. You get $7000 and 500xp for completing this.

This is where I found my answer: [Paradise Island Awards](http://paradiseislandhd.wikia.com/wiki/Awards)